# Getting pdf signatures with iText7

Tags: itext7

I have a scenario where I need to get signature information from a pdf with the iText7 library.  The signature may or may not exist. When I instantiate a new `SignatureUtil` object for a PDF that does not have any digital signatures I get the exception

> "There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects."

. If an signature is there it works fine.  I'm not sure how to correct this exception.

UPDATED to include code sample

```
Using reader As New PdfReader(pdfPath),
            pdf As New PdfDocument(reader)

                Dim util As New SignatureUtil(pdf)

                Dim signModel As String = "[Signature: {0} - {1}]"

                For Each signame As String In util.GetSignatureNames()
                    Dim whoisthis As PdfSignature = util.GetSignature(signame)
                    returnVal &= String.Format(
                        signModel,
                        whoisthis.GetName(),
                        whoisthis.GetReason
                        )
                Next

        End Using
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: updated to include my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is thrown because there is no AcroForm in the document and `SignatureUtil` tries to add it, but there is no associated `PdfWriter`.

As a workaround you can check if a document contains an AcroForm:

```
PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(document, false) != null
```

And only create `SignatureUtil` if **there is** an AcroForm. If there is no AcroForm there will be no signature fields.

Comment: That should be added to the `SignatureUtil` constructor JavaDocs.

Comment: I totally agree with you @mkl. This class is to be refactored as well.